# having issue with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code in my UIViewController and I am testing for iOS 5 in a device and both simultor.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (IS_IPHONE){
        return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint and it is indeed getting called, however it still rotates to landscape. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you told it to do so. `return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;` means that you want to autorotate to **every direction except portrait upside-down,** and that includes landscape. For iPad, even this constraint is missing, so it will autrotate to any orientation.

(You should have a fresh breath of documentation...)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

> return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);